# http401EntryPoint for Spring Security through HttpStatusEntryPoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

So there is *http403EntryPoint* that we can use as an attribute *entry-point-ref* for Spring security config

```
<http auto-config='false' use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
 <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>
```

But I want to distinguish 401 UNAUTHORIZED and 403 FORBIDDEN for the client, so I could provide login page while 401 and NO ACCESS page while 403.

There's no http401EntryPoint actually, but we can use org.springframework.http.HttpStatus class and pass HttpStatus into it's bean.

I tried:

```
 <http auto-config='false' use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="http401EntryPoint">
 <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
</http>
```

```
<beans:bean id="UNAUTHORIZED" class="org.springframework.http.HttpStatus">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="value" value="#{new Integer(401)}"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="reasonPhrase" value="#{new String(Unauthorized)}"/>
</beans:bean>
```

But it's still give me an error:

```
SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#183e819c' of type [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#183e819c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'http403EntryPoint' while setting bean property 'authenticationEntryPoint'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'http403EntryPoint' defined in file [C:\Users\k.mezhentsev\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\fooConfig\fooSecurity.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'UNAUTHORIZED' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 11): Property or field 'Unauthorized' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
```

What might be a problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I got it.

```
<beans:bean id="http401EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="httpCode401"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="httpCode401" class="org.springframework.http.HttpStatus" factory-method="valueOf">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:value>UNAUTHORIZED</beans:value>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```